# How do I create a unique ID in javascript each time a function is called?

Tags: javascript

Here's the function:

```
function addAttachment() {
    if (allowed_attachments <= 0)
         return alert("', $txt['more_attachments_error'], '");

    document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {                                                
         document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
    };


    setOuterHTML(document.getElementById("moreAttachments"), 
        \'<div class="upload_attachment">\
            <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="File">\
            <label class="custom-file-input">\
                <input type="file" id="uploadBtn" name="attachment[]">\
            </label></div><span id="moreAttachments">\
        </span>\');
    allowed_attachments = allowed_attachments - 1;
    return true;
}
```

UploadBtn and UploadFile need to be unique everytime, how do I do this? I'm really stuck

Comment: How unique must "unique" be? Globally unique? Sufficiently unique within a certain time frame for one user?

Comment: Short answer: generate a sufficiently large random number.

Comment: You can check out [Mongoh's Truly Uniquie ID](https://github.com/mongoh/tuid)

Answer (score 2):

Use a global object (out of the scope of `addAttachement`) like this:

```
var UNIQUE_ID = 0; // the ID counter (will be incremented each time a new item is created so it'll be unique)

function addAttachment() {
    if (allowed_attachments <= 0)
         return alert("', $txt['more_attachments_error'], '");

    document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {                                                
         document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
    };

    UNIQUE_ID++; // increment the ID counter

    setOuterHTML(document.getElementById("moreAttachments"), 
        '<div class="upload_attachment">\
            <input id="uploadFile' + UNIQUE_ID + '" placeholder="File">\
            <label class="custom-file-input">\
                <input type="file" id="uploadBtn' + UNIQUE_ID + '" name="attachment[]">\
            </label></div><span id="moreAttachments' + UNIQUE_ID + '">\
        </span>');
    allowed_attachments = allowed_attachments - 1;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use date object method now `Date.now()`

Comment: Will not be good enough if the id needs to be *globally unique*…

Comment: It will be always unique. Every time you enter `Date.now()` it will give you current timestamp. You can verify in console hitting this 2-3 times.

Comment: *Globally* unique means this still has to be unique even if two different people do it at the exact same time…!